# Replace some elements of numpy.ndarray with zero given another numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'd need to know the most efficient way for the following case. There is a numpy.ndarray of shape 11k*11k for which I need to force all elements of some rows to be zero given a binary numpy array of shape 11k. A toy example could be described as follows:

Inputs:

```
x = np.array([[2, 1, 1, 2],
              [0, 2, 1, 0],
              [1, 0, 1, 1],
              [2, 2, 1, 0]])
```

```
ref = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0])
```

Output:

```
y = ([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Extend `ref` to 2D and multiply - `x*ref[:,None]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this -

```
y = np.multiply(x.T,ref).T
```

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```